# exact example for JMS Topic in HornetQ

Tags: jms, publish-subscribe, hornetq

I read the hornetQ documentation, confused a lot. Can someone give an exact example to create a JMS topic in hornetQ. I mean the xml configurations in `hornetq-jms.xml` and `hornetq-configuration.xml`. assume we have a topic named `top` and 2 subscribers named: `sub1`, `sub2`. what I get is that we should define two queues(one for each subscribers) and bind them to an address which is the topic name actually, but how the subscriber would know they should connect to which one?(They only know the topic name)

Comment: You should accept the answer. Someone gave you some work for free, and you could at least give him the points for the answer he gave you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confused by the way HornetQ handles topics internaly in contrast to the way the JMS specification describes topics.

Let's start with the JMS specification. Here you have one topic, where n subscribers can listen to the messages, that will be published by a client. In JMS we talk only about the destination in singular, eg. we'll send a message to *the* topic, or *the* queue respectively.

HornetQ is a JMS Provider - a server that implements the JMS specification, so Java-clients can connect to it, and use the JMS-API. The JMS Provider might change, but the code should still work when using another JMS provider.

However, HornetQ does not distinguish internally the destinations (topic or queue), since it tries to be a generic messaging middleware. In HornetQ all topics or queues are implemented as "addresses" and "queues". When you use the HornetQ API (CoreAPI) instead of the JMS-API, you have to deal with such things. You should read the Address section in the [HornetQ documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#d0e1478):

> In core, there is no concept of a Topic, Topic is a JMS only term.
>   Instead, in core, we just deal with addresses and queues.
>
> For example, a JMS topic would be implemented by a single address to
>   which many queues are bound. Each queue represents a subscription of
>   the topic. A JMS Queue would be implemented as a single address to
>   which one queue is bound - that queue represents the JMS queue.

For an example how to use a topic with JMS via HornetQ, I stongly recommend the examples that come with HornetQ itself. After donwloading and extracting the hornetq archive, just go to the `examples/jms/topic` directory and see the readme.html for a brief overview how to implement and how to execute the example (`mvn verify`).

Comment: +1... Majid Azimi is confusing JMS Concepts with Core concepts. All he has to do is to add it to hornetq-jms.xml

Comment: I believe that it is important to give a concrete example to support the explanation you provided