# How to implement consumer-producer with multiple consumers and multiple queues

Tags: java, concurrency, messaging, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent

Assume there are 1 producer P and 2 consumers C1 and C2. And there are 2 queues Q1 and Q2, both with a specific capacity.

P will produce items and put it into Q1 and Q2 alternately. Item is produced for specific consumer and cannot be consumed by other consumers. How can I implement the following in Java: After I start the 3 threads, if Q1 is empty, thread C1 is blocked until it is notified when there is something in Q1. So is Q2. And P will be blocked when both Q1 and Q2 are full until it is notified when either Q1 or Q2 is not full.

I was thinking to use BlockingQueue, which will block a consumer when its queue is empty. But the problem is when either of queues is full, the producer will be blocked. Is there any data structure in Java we can use to solve this problem?

Update

I've got a solution myself, but I'm not sure whether it is efficient. We can still have 2 BlockingQueues. And when consumer take item from its queue, it uses `BlockingQueue.take()`, so it will be blocked when there is no item in the queue. When producer add item to either queue, it uses `BlockingQueue.offer()`. So that it will never be blocked by this operation and will get 'false' if the queue is full. In addition, we keep a AtomicInteger to indicate the number of queues which is not full. Every time when producer P want to put an item in a queue, if it get false return, we decrease the AtomicInteger by 1. When it reaches 0, the producer call `AtomicInteger.wait()`. Every time when a consumer takes an item from its queue, it also examines the AtomicInteger. When it is 0, the consumer increase it by 1 and call `AtomicInteger.notify()`.

Please let me know whether this solution makes sense.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `P will be blocked when both Q1 and Q2 are full` Blocked on *what*, Q1, Q2 or some other synchronizer?

Comment: You may not need two queues.  Use a single BlockingQueue, call `offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` from the producer and call `take` from the consumers, and then you don't need to worry about uneven queue sizes

Comment: Hi Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot, thank you. I modified the question, "Item is produced for specific consumer and cannot be consumed by other consumers." So I don't know whether in this case we can use a single BlockingQueue. This is actually a real problem I met.

Comment: Hi John Vint, thank you. P is supposed to be blocked util either of the queue is not full. It doesn't matter what it is blocked on.

Comment: In that case it makes sense to use separate queues.  Use `offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` from the producer and `take` from consumers so that the three threads will block until space / items are available.  If you want to still be able to produce items for queue1 when queue2 is full or vice versa then you probably want two producers instead of one.

Comment: If `Q1` is full is it ok for `P` to continue putting items in `Q2`?

Comment: Hi Miserable Variable, Yes.

Comment: Hi Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot, I added a possible solution in the post. Not sure whether it is efficient.

Comment: When you call `BlockingQueue.offer` and it returns false, what are you doing with the item that you produced?  I.e. are you discarding it?  If you're not able to discard it then you'll still need to have the producer block (or else you'll need to store the item somewhere else).  The problem with your `AtomicInteger.wait()` idea is that `wait` can only be called within a `synchronized` block/method, so if you're not careful then this will cause a lot of lock contention; however, if you make the `synchronized` block sufficiently fine-grained then your solution should work fine

Comment: Another option is to have the producer `sleep` when `AtomicInteger` reaches 0, and have a consumer `interrupt` the producer when it increments `AtomicInteger` - just be sure to have a `catch(InterruptException)` block in the producer that discards the exception.  There is a potential data race here if `AtomicInteger` decrements to 0, followed by a consumer incrementing `AtomicInteger` and interrupting the producer, followed by the producer sleeping; you'll need something like an `AtomicBoolean running` that is true when the producer is running and false when it is sleeping, then your

Comment: consumer will call `interrupt` if `AtomicInteger > 0 && !running` which takes care of the data race

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a [Striped Executor Service](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html). This will allow you to solve your problem **and** put your consumers into a pool which would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to only use java concurrency without other libraries?

Comment: That's not another library, it's a class that uses standard Executor Service functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use topics from the framework.

In activemq http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html

in hornetq [exact example for JMS Topic in HornetQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187030/exact-example-for-jms-topic-in-hornetq)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to only use java concurrency without other libraries?

Comment: Well, if you want to implement the design pattern of producer/consumer (of the standart JMS) you must have use a third party library

Answer (score 0):

No matter which data structure/messagig server you choose, you can go out of resources with any of these. There is always a limit on memory or disk space.

So actually it's not bad that the producer is stopped.

If your queues are filling up, you should try to restore the **balance**: You could add more consumers. You could improve the consumer's performance. If this is not possible, something should really throttle the producer. It's a way to avoid *out of memory errors* or *no space left on device*.

Finally it's the data center's duty to monitor the queues anyway. They should inform you, if the filling degree of your queues reaches a limit, for example > 80%.

*Update*

If the producer cannot send on all queues, because one of its queues is full, it is up to him to buffer, but buffering is something the queues should do.