# How do you listen to a JMS topic using Spring JMS

Tags: java, jms, hornetq, spring-jms, jms-topic

I have a HornetQ server which has topic and queue's. I am not aware of the config on the other side but the way I connect to the Queue is:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref ="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
    <property name="deliveryMode" value="2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="QUEUE_NAME"/>
</bean>

<!-- Listener Asynchronous -->
<bean id="queueListener" class="com.my.queueListener"/>

<jms:listener-container concurrency="5-10">
             <jms:listener destination="QUEUE_NAME" ref="queueListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

I had set the `pubSubDomain` to `true` and it worked (strange but true). Anyhow now I want to connect to a topic. I set the `pubSubDomain` as `true` and still it gives me an error saying

> WARNING: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Activate_NTD' - trying to recover. Cause: There is no queue with name TOPIC_NAME

I know HornetQ behaves a bit differently as specified here:

[exact example for JMS Topic in HornetQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187030/exact-example-for-jms-topic-in-hornetq)

but I am unable to figure out what to do and how to get this working.

Comment: The error message indicates that the message listener has its `pubSubDomain` flag set to `false`. The `DestinationResolver` is trying to resolve a **queue** and not a **topic**. Note that setting the flag on the `JmsTemplate` is useless for receiving messages, you need to set that on the `jms:listener-container` element.

Comment: Yes as Stephane pointed out you need to set  destination-type="topic" in jms-listner-container

Comment: ok. let me try that out. i thought i was missing something. hopefully this resolves it.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll and karthik thanks for the help.. set the destination-type="topic" in the jms-listener. thanks a tonn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `destination-type` on the container that defaults to queue, something like

```
<jms:listener-container destination-type="topic" concurrency="5-10">
         <jms:listener destination="TOPIC_NAME" ref="topicListener"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Comment: Finally, I am clear that I want to use **destination-type="topic"**, for my listener to work but here comes a major issue, Can we do this with JAVA DSL?

Comment: Sure thing. there is a setter for that as well.

Comment: I am using **DefaultMessageListenerContainer** and I can not see any setter for that property. After digging a bit found a way to solve it. Please see to my comment in the link over SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212488/what-is-the-equivalent-of-destination-type-from-jmslistener-container-in-javaco/37027806#37027806

Comment: Reading the doc might help `setPubSub(true)` creates a listener for a topic. Actually the answer in the link you provide tells you exactly that.